# Cannot write to sdcard on android emulator: permission denied; storage state: mounted

Tags: android, android-emulator, profiling, android-sdcard

I am trying to use Debug.startMethodTracing("tracefile"). But I got the error that "E/art: Unable to open trace file '/sdcard/localExp.trace': Permission denied".

The following are what I have tried:

1. I did add "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" to AndroidManifest.xml

2.I used "Environment.getExternalStorageState()". The returned state is "mounted".

3.The application works on real device but got the error on emulator.

I searched a lot about this problem but still can't solve it.